# How to get if radio buttons are set

Tags: php, html

So i ve got 3 radio buttons in a html document. Then i simply try to get if one of the buttons is set and then to print a message for one of the ticked buttons.
They all are in a form.
my buttons are:

```
echo "<table border=0>";
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type=radio name=sg value=admin /> Administrator
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ";
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type=radio name=sg value=operator /> Operator
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ";
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type=radio name=sg value=member checked=checked /> member
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ";
        echo "</table>";
```

The way i try to get them is:

```
if(isset($_GET['member'])) {
            echo "m is set!";
        }
        if(isset($_GET['admin'])) {
            echo "a is set!";
        }
        if(isset($_GET['operator'])) {
            echo "op is set!";
        }
```

This doesnt print anything, means none of the statements in the if clauses are true.
How do i get them?

Comment: isset($_GET['sg']

Comment: @RamKesavan I thought about that too but since i got 3 buttons how i then identify which button specificly is set?
Even thought none of of the if clauses is true with sg as its GET parameter.

Comment: if($_GET['sg'] == "admin").is it ok

Comment: @RamKesavan works just fine, thank you!

Comment: you should specify like this <input type="radio" name="sg" value="operator"> . Try editing the html and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the value of the input incorrectly, like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['member']))
```

instead of the name of the HTML element, like this:

```
  if(isset($_GET['sg'])){ 
      if($_GET['sg'] == "member") {
        echo "m is set!";
     }
     if($_GET['sg'] == "admin") {{
        echo "a is set!";
     }
     if($_GET['sg'] == "operator"){
        echo "op is set!";
     }
  }
```

Comment: accept the answer so that others can easily find their answer

Comment: I will, but for some reason it still takes like 7 more minutes.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: vMysterion access the value of input wrongly..accessed like this if(isset($_GET['member'])) instead of name of html element @showdev